# Bash Script that downloads a file and checks the value if 1 or 0

Tags: linux, debian, bash, wget

I need a Bash Script for Debian which downloads a file, that file containts 1 or 0, 1 when the services is running, 0 when not. So how can I check if the file contains 1 or 0?

Comment: Downloads how? By HTTP? FTP? STFP? The "wget" tag implies HTTP, but would be good to be explicit.

Comment: wget http://yoursite.com/status.php

Comment: We generally don't write scripts for people - we prefer them to have a go themselves and then show their working when asking for help debugging.

Comment: Why do you need this? Why 0 and 1, why not 200 status. Why not a monitoring solution? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bourne shell generically has a nice way to evaluate the contents of a string (not using test or [[ or whatever).

```
contents=$(curl -s http://path/to/thing/with/zero_or_one)

case "$contents"
in
  '1') echo "it was one"
      ;;
  '2') echo "it was two"
      ;;
   *)  echo "it was something else
      ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:-

```
status="$(curl -s http://yoursite.com/status.php)"
if [[ $status =~ ^1 ]]; then
  # site is up...
fi
```

Comment: Dosent works i get line 3: =1: command not found, line 3 is if [[ in my script

Comment: Oops typo .. now fixed